# AWS CloudWatch alarm for SQS Number of Messages Visible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to capture the event of a new message in my FIFO queue (as I want to avoid , infinite polling of Queue) .

For this purpose I am evaluating the CloudWatch alarm option with metrics ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible .

Following is my Alarm description-

**Threshold**: The condition in which the alarm will go to the ALARM state.ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible >= 0 for 1 minute

**Actions**:The actions that will occur when the alarm changes state.
In ALARM:
Send message to topic "topic_for_events_generated_bycloudwatch" (xyz@xyz)
Send message to topic "topic_for_events_generated_bycloudwatch"

**Period**:The granularity of the datapoints for the monitored metric.1 minute

Following are my queries -

1. Assuming there are more than 0 messages in the given Q - will this alarm raised only once when the condition met or every minute ?
2. During quick test I saw Alarm keeping moving between INSUFFICIENT and ALARM state in random other without any configuration changes, what could be rational ?

[Screenshot of ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible  metric graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wz6D.png)
[Screenshot of the log activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6oQY.png)

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Rohan K

Answer (score 3):

Cloudwatch will alarm once the threshold is breached for state transition.

[From the Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html)

> Alarms invoke actions for sustained state changes only. CloudWatch alarms do not invoke actions simply because they are in a particular state, the state must have changed and been maintained for a specified number of periods.

But

> After an alarm invokes an action due to a change in state, its
>   subsequent behavior depends on the type of action that you have
>   associated with the alarm. For Amazon EC2 and Auto Scaling actions,
>   the alarm continues to invoke the action for every period that the
>   alarm remains in the new state. **For Amazon SNS notifications, no additional actions are invoked.**

An Example:

> In the following figure, the alarm threshold is set to 3 units and the
>   alarm is evaluated over 3 periods. That is, the alarm goes to ALARM
>   state if the oldest of the 3 periods being evaluated is breaching, and
>   the 2 subsequent periods are either breaching or missing. In the
>   figure, this happens with the third through fifth time periods, and
>   the alarm's state is set to ALARM. At period six, the value dips below
>   the threshold, and the state reverts to OK. Later, during the ninth
>   time period, the threshold is breached again, but for only one period.
>   Consequently, the alarm state remains OK.

[image]

Comment: Looks like the behavior is not consistent and my SNS event is getting trigger even if ALARM is in ALARM state.